# Enable field formatter settings

Tags: entities, display-suite

I have a field that I created using hook_field_extra_fields, and I want it to have a cogwheel like in the image below, so that I can customize it. Right now the only format setting for the field is "Visible". Any ideas on how to enable the formatter settings for that field?

Note that I am also using display suite.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hook_field_formatter_settings_form` to add formatting of the field as shown in example below:

```
function example_field_formatter_info() {
  $info = array();
  $info['default_formatter'] = array(
    'label' => t('Show as link'),
    'field types' => array('example_field_type'),
     'settings' => array('target' => '_blank'), // <--- THIS
  );
  return $info;
}

function example_field_formatter_settings_form($field, $instance, $view_mode, $form, &$form_state) {
  $display = $instance['display'][$view_mode];
  $settings = $display['settings'];
  $element = array(); 
  if ($display['type'] == 'default_formatter') {
    $element['target'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => t('HREF target'),
      '#options' => array('_blank' => 'New window', '_self' => 'Same window'),
      '#default_value' => $settings['target'],
      '#description' => t('Control where the link opens (i.e. set the TARGET attribute of the A element).'),
    );
  }
  return $element;
}

function example_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {
  $settings = $display['settings']; // Key needs to be defined in info array (who knew?)
  $element = array();
  if ($display['type'] == 'default_formatter') {
    $target = $settings['target'];
    foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
      $element[$delta]['#markup'] = "<a href=\"{$item['href']}\" target=\"{$target}\">{$item['label']}</div>";
    }
  }
  return $element;
}
```

Update #1:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_settings_summary().
 */
function example_field_formatter_settings_summary($field, $instance, $view_mode) {
  $display = $instance['display'][$view_mode];
  $settings = $display['settings'];
  $summary = t('Show as link'); // we use t() for translation and placeholders to guard against attacks
  return $summary;
}
```

Comment: To show cogwheel, you need to implement `hook_field_formatter_settings_summary()` as shown in **Update #1**

Comment: `hook_field_formatter_settings_summary()` doesn't seem to be called. I should call it like this: `MY_MODULE_field_formatter_settings_summary()`, right?

Comment: correct, you need to replace hook word by your module name.